# Serializing multidimensional arrays to JSON with JAXB and MOXy

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I'm serializing next two-dimensional string array with JAXB/MOXy:

```
@XmlElement(name = "row")
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "rows")
private String[][] rows;
```

and I want it to be serialized to next JSON:

```
"rows": [
 ["1", "2"],
 ["3","4"],
 ["5","6"]
]
```

but I get this instead:

```
"rows": [
        {
            "item": ["1","2"]
        },
        {
            "item": ["1","2"]
        },
        {
            "item": ["1","2"]
        }
 ]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The current support for multi-dimensional arrays in MOXy matches the XML representation as defined in the JAXB specification.  I will update this answer once I have come up with an appropriate workaround for you.

Below is an enhancement request that you can use to track our first-class support for this use case:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/389815

Comment: @Blaise Any news on this?